# Как установить stylesheet для собственного класса?

Tags: c++, qt5

Допустим у меня есть класс `something` унаследованный от `QWidget` и завернутый в пространство имен `any` - как через `.qss` установить для него стиль (содержимое файла выкачивается в `main` и передается в `QApplication`)? Тобишь если сделаю так:

```
QWidget {
    background-color : green;    
}
```

То тогда все потомки `QWidget` будут иметь этот цвет в качестве `background` что, конечно, не желательно. А такое:

```
any::somthing {
    background-color : red;
}
```

То ничего не работает. Как сделать правильно?

UPD нашел решение: вместо `::` для пространства имен нужно использовать `--` и все заработает

Comment: setObjectName('style-selector');

Comment: @goldstar_labs подскажите как и где это использовать?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#objectName-prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня примерно так сделано:

В конструкторе класса `setObjectName("b_blue");`

```
QMyButton : public QPushButton
{
   QMyButton()
   {
      ...
      setObjectName("b_blue");
      ...
   }
}
```

В .qss

```
QPushButton#b_blue
{
    background: #255983;
    font: bold 28px;
    color: #66B5FF;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #66B5FF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
}
QPushButton#b_blue:focus
{
    color: #00E5FF;
    border-color: #00E5FF;
    background: #007AFF;
    outline: none;
}
```

Таким образом все созданные объекты класса QMyButton будут искать стиль b_blue.

Также стиль можно менять в динамике

```
my_button->setObjectName("b_blue");
my_button->style()->unpolish(my_button);
my_button->style()->polish(my_button);
```