# Как установить stylesheet для собственного класса в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qss

Такой же вопрос, но для *C++* уже был задан на сайте ([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868552/Как-установить-`stylesheet`-для-собственного-класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868552/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%60stylesheet%60-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)), но решение которое там представлено нельзя переделать для *Python*, хотя проблема идентична.

Если кто знает решение на *Python* для *PyQt5*, прошу ответить.

**МВП:**

Главный модуль

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    pass
```

Файл `stylesheet_1` (работает, но для всех `QWidget`, вместо конкретного наследника)

```
QWidget {
    background-color : green;   
}
```

Файл `stylesheet_2` (не работает)

```
MyWidget {
    background-color : green;   
}
```

Comment: Вам обязательно ответят, но пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick, Исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы предоставили - не является минимально-воспроизводимым примером. Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте МВП.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName('mywidget')
        
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setObjectName('widget')
        btn = QPushButton('Это кнопка')
        hlayout = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        hlayout.addWidget(btn)
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        

STYLE_SHEET = '''
#mywidget {
    background-color: #008d32;
}
#widget {
    background-color: #ef8d32;
}
QPushButton {
    background: #255983;
    font: bold 28px;
    color: #66B5FF;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #66B5FF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    color: #00E5FF;
    border-color: #00E5FF;
    background: #007AFF;
    outline: none;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]